# Angular: emulate on specific webkit

Tags: angularjs, webkit, gecko

I am working on an `Angular` app that will be deployed on webkit :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Qt/4.8.0 Safari/534.34
```

when I test in Chrome or Firefox everything works fine but when I run the app on webkit, some elements are not showing among other problems. How could I have test environment for that webkit on my windows 7 OS to test my `Angular` app before deploy it on the machine?